# Why is the electric potential formula like this and how is it derived?

Tags: electrical-engineering

So from what I could understand from my Electrical Engineering lectures the electric potential at a particular point charge $A$ is:

$u_A=-\int_{\infty}^{r_A}\overrightarrow{E}\overrightarrow{dr}$

The minus here might be a mistake on my side because I think since they're still written in vector form the minus should not be there. Not sure though.

But how is this formula derived? Why is it particularly the integral of $\overrightarrow{E}\overrightarrow{dr}$? Btw I'm a beginner in this field so please go easy with the electrical engineering jargon.

Comment: How familiar are you with the concept of force and work ? Are you familiar with the formula $\vec{F}\cdot \vec{ds}$ involving the force $\vec{F}$ and the infinitesimal distance $\vec{ds}$ ??

Comment: Well I know the formula of work is $W=F\cdot s$, but I'm not sure what the infinitesimal distance is. I suppose $F\cdot ds$ is used to determine the work over a really short distance or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula for (small amount of) work done ($dW$) on a body to move it over a (small) distance $\vec{dr}$ using force $\vec{F}$ is given by the *dot product*
$$dW = \vec{F}\cdot\vec{dr}$$

In electrostatics, the force acting on a charged particle is proportional to its charge $q$ and the electric field $\vec{E}_{(\vec{r})}$ at *that* point $\vec{r}$ where the charge is situated. So work done *by the electric field* is
$$dW = q\ \vec{E}_{(\vec{r})}\cdot\vec{dr}$$

If we want to move a charge against the force from the electric field (very slowly), we need to apply an equal and opposite force on the charge (we don't have to apply a force greater than the electric field since we don't intend to accelerate the charged particle. Remember, this is only a thought process used for understanding the formula. More details at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential)). Then, the work *done against the electric field* is
$$dW = (-1) q\ \vec{E}_{(\vec{r})}\cdot\vec{dr}$$

With suitable assumptions, the work that would have been done on the particle to bring it from an infinite distance away to the location $r_A$ *against the force from the electric field* is then (by "*summing*" up the tiny work done over tiny distances from infinity to $r_A$)

$$W = q\ \int_{\infty}^{\vec{r}_A} (-1)\vec{E}_{(\vec{r})}\cdot\vec{dr}$$

Potential is now *defined as* the work done *per unit charge*.
From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential)

> The electric potential is defined as the amount of work energy needed to move a unit of electric charge from a reference point to the specific point in an electric field. ... By definition, the electric potential at the reference point is zero units. Typically, the reference point is earth **or a point at infinity**, although any point can be used.

So potential becomes

$$u_A = - \int_{\infty}^{\vec{r}_A} \vec{E}_{(\vec{r})}\cdot\vec{dr}$$

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot. But could you please elaborate on why the $-1$ is added after we take the integral of both sides?

Comment: The `-1` can be put on a separate step on its own with its own explanation. Edited the answer.